# Mail App Showing As "talagent" in Mission Control

Tags: catalina, mail.app, mission-control

simple one just wondering why is my Apple Mail showing as "talagent" in mission control?
Any idea how it can be fixed?

- I do not realise when it switched to this name
- I tried rebooting and resetting RAM but it's still showing the same[image]

Comment: Wild guess… talagent is the service responsible for relaunching apps after a restart etc. Something has got confused, so try… Quit Mail, then  delete the contents of `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState/` (not the folder itself as it's an alias) Then relaunch Mail.

Comment: @Tetsujin amazing, I found the original folder, moved it to desktop for trial run and restarted Mail and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a wild guess in comments, which seems to have worked…

`talagent` is the service responsible for relaunching apps after a restart etc.
Something has got confused, so try…

Quit Mail, then delete the contents of
`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState/`
(not the folder itself as it's an alias) Then relaunch Mail.